# Modifying a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm using regex to look through a file to check for a username and whether their action caused an error or not (ERROR for error, INFO for successful action)
I am using a nested dictionary to keep track of actions, with the username as the primary key and the nested dictionary of how many INFO and ERROR lines they generate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

users = {}
with open('logfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        regex_user = r"(INFO|ERROR): .* \((.+)\)$"
        """searches for users and if there message was info or error"""
        user = re.serach(regex_user, line)
        if user is None:
            continue
        name = user[2]
        cat = user[1]
        try:
            # Method 1?
            users[name][cat] = users[name].get(cat, 0) + 1
            # Method 2?
            users[name][cat] = users.get(name, {}).get(cat, 0) + 1
        except KeyError:
            print("Where are my keys?")
```

I am wondering which of the two methods (if any) are correctly modifying the dictionary to increase the count of the respective nested key.

Output should look like:

```
{'John': {'INFO': 22, 'ERROR': 3}}
```

if the log contained 22 lines of INFO and 3 lines of ERROR for user John.

Comment: if there is no key `name` for `users` then method 2 will produce an error when you try to assign to `users[name][cat]`. You might want to check out `collections.defaultdict()`

Comment: If there is no key `name` for `users` then method 1 will produce an error when you try to get the value of `users[name]`. So neither works in the event that `name` is not a key in `users` already.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out collections.defaultdict()

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to solve this with a nested `collections.defaultdict` or alternatively using `setdefault()` though the latter is not a clean in my opinion. `collections.defaultdict()` will allow you to reference a dictionary key that does not yet exist which is the crux of your issue.

Try something like:

```
import collections
import json
import random

users = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
for i in range(100):
    user = random.choice(["John", "Jane", "Sanjay"])
    cat =  random.choice(["INFO", "ERROR"])
    users[user][cat] += 1

print(json.dumps(users, indent=2))
```

That will print out something like:

```
{
  "Jane": {
    "INFO": 16,
    "ERROR": 19
  },
  "John": {
    "ERROR": 21,
    "INFO": 10
  },
  "Sanjay": {
    "INFO": 18,
    "ERROR": 16
  }
}
```

though each run will be different.

As we noted by @Ryukashin, a `defaultdict()` does not `print()` as nicely as a `dict()`. So casting back is possilbe if it is really needed for some reason. The easiest (no not the most efficient) manner for that might be:

```
users = json.loads(json.dumps(users))
```

Comment: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000012EB5961240>, {'John': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 1}), 'Sally': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'ERROR': 2, 'INFO': 1}), 'Greg': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 1}), 'Marge': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 2})})

This comes up when I try to use collection.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int)) as you have. The dictionaries are printed out yet there is an error for lambda and class 'int'

Comment: There is no actual error. That is your "ERROR" cat you see. You may not expect this if what you are doing is `print(users)` as a `defaultdict()` does not print as nicely as a plain old `dict()`. If you really need a dict rather than a defaultdict as a type in the end for some reason then you can cast it all back.